# What's the difference between "the statement given" and "the given statement"?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I've stubbled upon these kind of phrases many times but I'm still not sure whether they are interchangeable or not. And also there's a similar phrase like "the invading barbarians", is it the same as if I word it as "the barbarians who are invading" for that matter, can it be used in every sentence?

Comment: I can't answer your main question but "the barbarians thats invading" isn't correct it should be "that are invading"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between "the given statement" and "the statement given". The other example that you give in your question is potentially more complex, and I am not going to say this answer applies to it or to attempt to address it.